# Call a Method from thread1 to thread2?

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronizationcontext

**First:** What I want to do?

1. I want to run multiple jobs on one thread, for example, I want to make a thread for calculations and always run methods inside of that.
2. Get a pointer like SynchronizationContext.Current or Thread.CurrentThread to access current job working.

3.A Cross-Platform way like Net Standard.

**Second:** Example-1 (CrossPlatform-Working) My example not working, because Post and Send method in SynchronizationContext don't work

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SynchronizationContext contextThread1 = null;
        SynchronizationContext contextThread2 = null;
        Thread thread1, thread2 = null;
        thread1 = new Thread(() =>
        {
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());
            contextThread1 = SynchronizationContext.Current;
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                if (contextThread2 != null)
                {
                    contextThread2.Post((state) =>
                    {
                        //Thread.CurrentThread == thread2 always false because the method is not runnig from thread 2
                        Console.WriteLine("call a method from thread 1 for thread 2 :" + (Thread.CurrentThread == thread2));
                    }, null);
                }
            }
        });
        thread1.IsBackground = true;
        thread1.Start();

        thread2 = new Thread(() =>
        {
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());
            contextThread2 = SynchronizationContext.Current;
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                if (contextThread1 != null)
                {
                    contextThread1.Post((state) =>
                    {

                        //Thread.CurrentThread == thread1 always false because the method is not runnig from thread 1
                        Console.WriteLine("call a method from thread 2 for thread 1 :"+(Thread.CurrentThread == thread1));
                    }, null);
                }
            }
        });
        thread2.IsBackground = true;
        thread2.Start();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Example-2: (No Cross PLatform because Windowsbase.dll): this example works fine but this is not cross platform.

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dispatcher contextThread1 = null;
        Dispatcher contextThread2 = null;

        Thread thread1, thread2 = null;
        thread1 = new Thread(() =>
        {
            contextThread1 = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
            Dispatcher.Run();
        });
        thread1.IsBackground = true;
        thread1.Start();

        thread2 = new Thread(() =>
        {
            contextThread2 = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
            Dispatcher.Run();
        });
        thread2.IsBackground = true;
        thread2.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (contextThread2 != null)
            {
                contextThread2.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    //Thread.CurrentThread == thread2 always false because the method is not runnig from thread 2
                    Console.WriteLine("call a method from thread 1 for thread 2 :" + (Thread.CurrentThread == thread2));
                }));
            }
            if (contextThread1 != null)
            {
                contextThread1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("call a method from thread 2 for thread 1 :" + (Thread.CurrentThread == thread1));
                }));
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Then maybe you should re-think the whole architecture after you read some material on the subject.

Comment: Why not using ordinary delegates to execute jobs? They (and optional parameters) can be enqueued in a synchronized queue and dequeued by the worker thread.

Comment: @KBO I want to run a method for thread 2 that executed from thread1 how delegates can fix this? I mean i want to make one thread bussy not another thread.and i don't want make new thread.

Comment: @KBO check my example 2 pls

Answer (score 3):

You should always use a tool these days to make your life easier where possible. In this case you should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework. Just NuGet "System.Reactive" and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;`.

Then you can do this:

```
void Main()
{
    var thread1 = new EventLoopScheduler();
    var thread2 = new EventLoopScheduler();

    Action action = () => Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    action();

    thread1.Schedule(action);

    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    thread2.Schedule(action);

    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    thread2.Schedule(() =>
    {
        action();
        thread1.Schedule(action);
    });

    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    action();
}
```

The kind of output I get is:

```
11
12
14
14
12
11
```

If you follow along with the code you can see it is correctly scheduling to each thread.

When you want to shut down just call `.Dispose()` on each `EventLoopScheduler`.

Comment: Works fine, can I know how its working in base? I'm investigating

Comment: I mean using net standard component without using any nuget packages,how it working

Comment: @AliYousefie - Why? Use a library that makes it easy for you. Otherwise you have to manage the lifetime of your thread. That's hard.

Comment: yea I know that is hard, but i'm not working for money or something like copy paste codes, I just went to know how it's works,because I am working on a big project like IIS (Server manager) I'm trying to make a faster and better way to manage clients

Comment: @AliYousefie - Why? I like driving a car, but I don't want to learn how to make one.